# pseudo-elements horizontal scrollbar positioned at the top of a div

Tags: html, css

I am using the following to display a horizontal scroll bar:

```
<div>
   <img src="http://placeimg.com/1000/300/any">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:15px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

However, as you can see from the [demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVdYpW), the scrollbar is only visible at the bottom of the div. Is there a way to position it at the top?

Comment: Scroll bar styling isn't supported in all browsers. I don't think Firefox or Internet Explorer (perhaps Edge too) support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZxNWb

I changed the HTML a bit:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/1000/150/any" alt="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

The original `div` is now a `div.wrapper`, and I added a `div.content` to hold all content.

Now the trick is simple, just flip the wrapper and then flip the content once more.

```
.wrapper, .content{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

The wrapper is now upside-down, so its scroll bar comes on top. The content is flipped twice so it stays the same.